# trying to activate pyenv, error: Load pyenv automatically by appending # the following to ~/.zshrc: eval "$(pyenv init -)

Tags: python, pyenv

i installed pyenv using homebrew, but when i try to activate pyenv with the command:

```
 pyenv shell 3.8.3,
```

i get the following message:

```
pyenv: shell integration not enabled. Run `pyenv init' for instructions.
```

So i run:

```
pyenv init
```

and then it says, "

```
# Load pyenv automatically by appending # the following to ~/.zshrc: eval "$(pyenv init -)
```

I don't know how to do this, does any1 know how to do this? I am running a mac os High Sierra 10.13.6

Ultimately, I want to use Python 3.7.4, this is why I installed pyenv. If i type

```
pyenv global 3.7.4
```

into the command line I get

```
pyenv: version `3.7.4' not installed
```

but i did install python 3.7.4. If I type

```
python -V
```

into the command line, I get Python 3.8.3. How do I install python3.7.4 so pyenv will see it. Also it should be noted, i've been having problems b4 with bash wherein i have to type:

```
PATH=/Users/myHomepage/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

to activate my virtual environment previously.

I saw a tutorial on how to Setup pyenv for Multiple Pythons" wherein he says we have to add settings to our bash profile to type the following three commands:

```
$ echo ‘export PYENV_ROOT=“$HOME/.pyenv”’ >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo 'export PATH=“$PYEN_ROOT/bin:$PATH” >>.bash.profile
$ echo ‘eval “$(pyenv init -)”’ >>~/.bash_profile
```

but i am using zsh so i input:

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

I only ran the two commands under zsh, I don't know if this is why I am getting an error message when I restarted zsh:

```
[oh-my-zsh] Insecure completion-dependent directories detected:
drwxrwxr-x  3 myHomepage  admin  102 Oct  7 20:04 /usr/local/share/zsh
drwxrwxr-x  4 myHomepage  admin  136 Oct  7 20:26 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions

[oh-my-zsh] For safety, we will not load completions from these directories until
[oh-my-zsh] you fix their permissions and ownership and restart zsh.
[oh-my-zsh] See the above list for directories with group or other writability.

[oh-my-zsh] To fix your permissions you can do so by disabling
[oh-my-zsh] the write permission of "group" and "others" and making sure that the
[oh-my-zsh] owner of these directories is either root or your current user.
[oh-my-zsh] The following command may help:
[oh-my-zsh]     compaudit | xargs chmod g-w,o-w

[oh-my-zsh] If the above didn't help or you want to skip the verification of
[oh-my-zsh] insecure directories you can set the variable ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX to
[oh-my-zsh] "true" before oh-my-zsh is sourced in your zshrc file.

➜  ~ exec "$SHELL"
[oh-my-zsh] Insecure completion-dependent directories detected:
drwxrwxr-x  3 myHomepage  admin  102 Oct  7 20:04 /usr/local/share/zsh
drwxrwxr-x  4 myHomepage  admin  136 Oct  7 20:26 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions

[oh-my-zsh] For safety, we will not load completions from these directories until
[oh-my-zsh] you fix their permissions and ownership and restart zsh.
[oh-my-zsh] See the above list for directories with group or other writability.

[oh-my-zsh] To fix your permissions you can do so by disabling
[oh-my-zsh] the write permission of "group" and "others" and making sure that the
[oh-my-zsh] owner of these directories is either root or your current user.
[oh-my-zsh] The following command may help:
[oh-my-zsh]     compaudit | xargs chmod g-w,o-w

[oh-my-zsh] If the above didn't help or you want to skip the verification of
[oh-my-zsh] insecure directories you can set the variable ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX to
[oh-my-zsh] "true" before oh-my-zsh is sourced in your zshrc file.
```

so I typed:

```
compaudit | xargs chmod g-w,o-w
```

but still got:

```
There are insecure directories:
```

so then I put this in the command line:

```
exec "$SHELL"
```

then I installed python 3.7.4 into my folder project, it seems to be working, but I'm not sure about the error message " There are insecure directories:"

Comment: `‘` `“` `”` `’` are unicode characters. Shell syntax requires balanced use of standard `'` & `"` quotes.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you cite 3 commands to run in bash profile config file. And you say that you are using zsh, but show only the 2 first commands. Do you run the 3 command to zsh config file? Like:

```
$ echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: I only ran the two commands under zsh, see my answer above, I'm not sure if this is why I am getting the message: "There are insecure directories:"-thnx

Comment: I'm not a user of MAC, but the message of insecure directories on your question seems like permission and owner problem, like I see in Linux env.

Comment: now I put "$ echo ‘eval “$(pyenv init -)”’ >>~/.zshrc" into the command line, restarted zsh and now am getting this error message upon opening zsh: /Users/myHomepage/.zshrc:105: parse error near `then'" - i'm not sure what to do...

Comment: @JohnHarbaugh This post incorrectly used unicode quotes instead of normal single and double quotes. Your config probably needs fixing.

Comment: Sorry for my typo. I'm only copy and paste your example and change the config file name. You will need access the .zshrc file with some editor with your terminal and fix it (I'm not know if MAC has some method to access this files on explorer). In a linux env you would use "vi ~/.zshrc" (where vi are the editor cmd) to do access it.